# SqlDateTime overflow.. Will this cause any issues ? is any kind of hacking or bypassing age restriction is possible in this case?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, security

We have a website with age restriction. If a user want to register in our website, user must be 18 years old. As i know there is validation at client and server side ?

When i tried to register in our website i just opened inspect element in the form field and added "0001" in year list, after submitting the form am getting error like ( Near button)

```
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 
1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZVEz.png)

Will this cause any issues? If yes what are those? Is this possible for any kind of hacking or bypassing age restriction in this case?

Comment: If you can open an element and change the year, then I would say, "yes", you do have a hacking problem with getting around the age restriction.  You haven't figured out how to exactly do it, but someone else probably could.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff
As i know there is validation at client and server side ? still it is possible to hack or bypass age restriction ?  except these any other issues are possible like inserting NULL values etc...? i Googled for it but i did't found more information on this. Could you please provide me more information on this.

Comment: Generally one should not show details of unexpected errors to the user as it exposes details of the technologies used, making it easier for a bad actor to exploit. It would be better to log those errors and show a generic something went wrong message. Value validation can also be done on the server side as a precaution.